# How to use the Find and Replace Dialog Window?

Tags: documentation

The Find edit box in the Find and Replace Dialog Window shows a default word while opening. How do I tell it to show the word in which the mouse cursor is located in the Notebook, rather than the last word searched for?

I want it to work like pressing F1 to open the right reference in Documentation Center does.

Comment: `Ctrl+.` followed by `Ctrl+F` makes the word in cursor position appear in the input field of the Find& Replace dialog box.

Answer (score 3):

The exact behavior of the find and replace dialog has changed from version 7 to version 8. It might be of interest which version you are using.

Since version 8 the dialog will copy the current selection to its search input field as I think is common standard for editor like applications. You can use any known method to select what you want to search for, the suggested Ctrl+. keyboard shortcut probably being the most convenient.

For earlier version you would have to copy the selection and paste it to the search input field, e.g. with Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V on Windows or corresponding shortcuts for other OS.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get this question marked as answered. As kguler said in a comment: Ctrl+. followed by Ctrl+F (Windows). Ctrl+. followed by Cmnd+F (OS X).